# Variable won't pass over as an argument in AngularJS

Tags: forms, angularjs, attributes, arguments

I am new to AngularJS, and have come up on an issue with passing variables to a function in my controller. Here is the code in my HTML page:

```
<li ng-repeat="grade in grades">
   <span class="status-{{grade.status()}}" ng-hide="visible" focus="visible = true" blur="visible = false" ng-click="visible = true">{{grade.name}},</span>  
   <span class="status-{{grade.status()}}" ng-hide="visible" focus="visible = true" blur="visible = false" ng-click="visible = true">{{grade.score}}</span>
   <form ng-model="studentUpdForm" ng-submit="update({{grade.name}}, {{studentNameNew}}, {{grade.score}}, {{studentGradeNew}})" focus="visible = true" blur="visible = false" ng-show="visible">
         <input type="text" ng-model="studentNameNew" size="12" class="status-{{grade.status()}}" placeholder="{{grade.name}}" value="{{grade.name}}">, 
         <input type="text" ng-model="studentGradeNew" size="2" class="status-{{grade.status()}}" placeholder="{{grade.score}}" value="{{grade.score}}">                                                    <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="update">
    </form>
</li>
```

Here is the function the form points to:

```
$scope.update = function(thisName, newName, thisScore, newScore) {

    //run some code
};
```

What it's supposed to do: allow for the inline editing of a list item, generated from the array "grades", each item being "grade". Here's where I'm running into trouble: in calling the function $scope.update, the values for thisScore and newScore are passed in fine from the variables {{grade.score}} and {{studentGradeNew}}. However, the values I've trying to pass through for thisName and newName are not. When I send the arguments passed in to the console, I get this:

```
undefined undefined 98 88
```

I've been digging around to see why the old and new names are not passing over, but am at a loss. It's especially odd to me since the old and new score variables are passing successfully, and they are declared in relation to the form the same way as the names. I must be missing something, but can't think of what.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the {{}} in your function call. They aren't required. Not sure why it would still find some of the vars and not others, but in my plunker when I removed them, things started working.

Comment: That did it! Thanks, I was hoping it was something that simple.